# How to execute a command after 7 days?

Tags: date, math

Sorry for this newbie question but i tried to search for answers and I cant find an example with good explanations.

Can anyone show me how to add 7 days place this on the variable today7

```
REM get current date
set today=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~-7,2%

Rem add 7 days to variable today
set today7=today+7 days
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention. Im trying to create a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentexamples.php) will help you. (Google can be your friend)